# Showing square root symbol in tkinter label Python

Tags: python, unicode, tkinter, symbols

How do display the square root symbol in Tkinter, with numbers that actually look like they are in the root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be possible using U+221A (Square Root) and U+0305 (Combining Overline). However, the quality of the results will depend at lot on the fonts being used. Often, the overlines will appear completely misplaced - and even when they do work, there are likely to be gaps between the characters. Here's an example unicode string for sqrt(16):

```
'\u221A1\u03056\u0305'
```

and the result:

> √1̅6̅

However, the accepted convention is to avoid this and simply use the square root symbol alone (or perhaps also with parentheses):

> √16  or  √(16)